JavaScript expandable tabs open on page load ... need them closed
I have a script that shows a list of tabs/buttons. When a tab is clicked, the tab expands (showing more content), and it shows an image to the right. If you click another tab, the new tab expands and the other closes
I am having a problem making the tabs all be closed when a user goes to this page, but want all tabs to be closed ONLY if JavaScript sees a parent div tag with a specific class (i.e. if a div with a class tabsleft-container has another class called firsttabopen).
I set a conditional at the end of the JavaScript ... to check and see if a class exists (checks the div with tabsleft-container to see if the class firsttabopen exists). If the irsttabopen class exists, it should run the final changeTab line (that opens the first tab) ... but if the class doesn't exist, all the tabs should be closed when the page loads. However, the conditional isn't working. It is assuming the firsttabopen class exists, and is running the changeTab line always...
Note: Someone else coded the JavaScript for this and my knowledge of JavaScript is really limited.
The JavaScript is here:
$(document).ready(function () {
  const firstmenucontents = $(".tabsleft-container");

  firstmenucontents.each((index, firstmenucontent) => {
    const copy = $(firstmenucontent).find(".bannerpane img").clone();
    copy.css("visibility", "hidden");
    $(firstmenucontent).find(".bannerpane-container").append(copy);

    let selecteditem = 0;

    let textpaneItemIndex = -1;
    const changeTab = (index, item) => {
      var delay = 300;

      if (window.innerWidth < 980) {
        delay = 800;
      }
      if (textpaneItemIndex !== index) {
        if (textpaneItemIndex !== -1) {
          $(firstmenucontent)
            .find(".textpane-item-container")
            .eq(textpaneItemIndex)
            .children(".textpane-subitem")
            .slideUp(delay);
          $(firstmenucontent)
            .find(".textpane-item-container")
            .eq(textpaneItemIndex)
            .removeClass("clicked");
          $(firstmenucontent)
            .find(".textpane-item-container")
            .eq(textpaneItemIndex)
            .children(".textpane-item")
            .children("img")
            .css("transform", "");
          $(firstmenucontent)
            .find(".bannerpane")
            .eq(textpaneItemIndex)
            .removeClass("bannerpane-animation");
        }
        $(firstmenucontent)
          .find(item)
          .children(".textpane-subitem")
          .slideDown(delay);
        $(firstmenucontent).find(item).addClass("clicked");
        $(firstmenucontent)
          .find(".bannerpane")
          .eq(index)
          .addClass("bannerpane-animation");
        textpaneItemIndex = index;

        $(firstmenucontent)
          .find(item)
          .children(".textpane-item")
          .children("img")
          .css("transform", "rotate(-180deg)"); // Corrected typo herea
      }
    };
    $(firstmenucontent)
      .find(".textpane-item-container")
      .each((index, item) => {
        $(firstmenucontent)
          .find(item)
          .click(() => {
            changeTab(index, item);
            selecteditem = index;
          });
      });

        if($(firstmenucontents).hasClass('firsttabopen')) {
    changeTab(0, $(firstmenucontent).find(".textpane-item-container").eq(0));
}
  });
});

So, I changed classList to hasClass ... and that works ... HOWEVER, if there are two instances of tabsleft-container ... and only one contains the class firsttabopen ... then it runs the code above and the first tab is expanded on all sets of this code (it sees one instance, and runs it on all). I need the code to run changeTab on only the CHILDREN of the div that has the class firsttabopen.  So, I tried the following...
   if($(firstmenucontents).hasClass('firsttabopen')) {
        changeTab(0, $(firstmenucontent).find(".firsttabopen")
                  .children("textpane-item-container").eq(0));
    }

I figured that once it finds the item that has firsttabopen ... it will then find the firsttabopen, get the child textpane-item-container and then make it open (eq(0)).
But that doesn't work.
Here is a link to the full code in CodePen:
https://codepen.io/jabbamonkey/pen/eYoXJao

Please see Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?  Relevant code needs to be included in the question to produce a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, as well as information about the problem itself and what debugging you have done.

Having said that... Remove the last call to changeTab at the end.

I added my code in the question. Removing the last changeTab works... but doesn't allow me to easily turn it "on" and "off" (preferably by adding a class somewhere)

And when you make an attempt to build your intended functionality, what do you try and what doesn’t work as expected?

I don't know javascript very well... I assume I need to add a class to one of the upper level div tags... then use javascript to say, "Hey, if that tag exists, run the 'changeTab' code". If it doesn't ... do nothing (and it stays closed). But, I don't know how to do that...

It would seem then that your next step would be to start with some JavaScript tutorials and make an attempt to start building your functionality.  For example, if you want to check if an element exists on the page, that’s a specific operation you can look up and attempt to write.

I ran through some tutorials. I added a conditional at the end of the script... but it still isn't working. Hence, why I'm here.

Now that you're making an attempt... If you're not familiar with your browser's development/debugging tools, now is a great time to start.  If the if statement you added is being invoked at all, I'd expect it to produce an error.  You're trying to use a property called classList which doesn't exist on the jQuery object.  You may be looking for .hasClass() instead.  See this question about using jQuery to check if an element (or set of elements) has a particular class.

hasClass works, but there is still an issue. if there are two instances of tabsleft-container ... and only one contains the class "firsttabopen" ... then it runs the changeTab on all instances. So, I tried running changeTab using .children('') but it doesn't work....

Ok... I got it. This time it was a typo issue...

The first fix was to use .hasClass instead of .classList.
Then, it was a simple typo issue....
if($(firstmenucontents)...

changed to...
if($(firstmenucontent)

That's it. All fixed.
